# Odin Flashable Backup

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Ok.  So, lucky me, I just got a galaxy s4.  Unfortunately it's the AT&T version, already updated to MK2.

It is rooted, and I've gone through and removed all the bloatware apps through Titanium backup.

My question is, now that I've got this basic stock system, how can I make a Odin flashable tar out of it?  I mean a complete one... bootloader, system, phone, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately since you got it with mk2 you can't just install cwm or twrp. You can make a stock nandroid recovery backup. If you want to be able to flash roms in the future though, your going to need to look into the thread on XDA for your phone named Safestrap. I know they were working on getting it working on 4.3 but I'm not certain. It was originally made for anyone who took the mf3 firmware ota update which locked down the firmware and patched the loki exploit. I'm still using the old mdl bootloader so I haven't checked the status of Safestrap recently.

Comment: yeah, I do know that safestrap does work with this update.  I had another MK2 that I had before this one, and tested... had a custom rom installed in another slot...   I don't know how to make a nandroid backup tho...

Comment: I am creating a backup right now of the stock rom slot using SafeStrap.  Is there a way that I can convert that into something I could Odin flash?  I ask just in case I need to be able to do this after screwing up my phone LOL

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can get an Odin-flashable one, but you can do it with ClockWorkMod Recovery and then restore it with it.

You will have to install CWM recovery first if you don't have it already and then just make a backup which can be downloaded on the PC.

Comment: There is no CWM or TWRP for this.  Due to locked bootloader.  Safestrap does work though.